# Callbacks in bean lifecycle

Tags: java, spring

I was just going through spring documentation for Lifecycle callbacks for a bean. For initialization callback the documentation recommends using @PostConstruct annotation instead of using the InitializingBean interface implementation as it couples code with Spring. Could someone please explain what they mean when they say coupling code with spring. I will share the link to the section i was going through [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-initializingbean).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InitializingBean` is pure Spring and will only work in Spring. `@PostConstruct` is ordinary Java 1.8. Sadly, from 9 it's dependent on `javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2`

Answer (score 1):

The `@PostContruct` annotation is not Spring-specific, but from [Jakarta Annotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Annotations). This way, the core part of your code is not tied to Spring specifically, but could also work in a non-Spring environment, including any [Jakarta EE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_EE) implementation (see "Certified referencing runtimes" in the article), for example, GlassFish or WildFly.

Here is the relevant Javadoc from the Jakarta documentation: [PostConstruct](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/10/apidocs/jakarta/annotation/postconstruct).

Comment: Also if you could give an example of a non spring environment and why would i wanna run a spring app in it?

Comment: See my addition. Of course, you can't run a complete Spring app in a non-Spring environment, but if your core classes don't depend on Spring, migrating will be easier. There are also non-EE libraries like Guice that may support `@PostConstruct`, although Guice does not at the moment: https://github.com/google/guice/issues/1490